# CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW sql error

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-design

Trying to update a [table view](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_view.asp) using:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW [vtable] AS SELECT * FROM Files_Table ORDER BY File
```

The table is returning the old view, not the updated.

Statement tested in the Sqlite database browser:

```
Error message from database engine: near "OR": syntax error
```

but didn't get this in the program?

Any idea why it's not updating?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

SQLite does not support the CREATE OR REPLACE syntax. The only database that I know which supports that syntax is Oracle, but I am guessing there are others.

Drop the view and create it with the new definition:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS [vtable]; -- "OR REPLACE"
CREATE VIEW [vtable] AS SELECT * FROM Files_Table ORDER BY File;
```

Comment: Yeah, SQL Server 2005 definitely doesn't support that functionality- much to my chagrin.

Comment: yup, just saw that, thanks: Views are read-only in SQLite. http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html

Comment: PostgreSQL has it too http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-createview.html

Comment: MySQL supports it too. More information here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html -- this comment is by @hlascelles

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error when using CREATE OR REPLACE in MS SQL Server. The following worked for me:

```
ALTER VIEW [vtable] AS
SELECT *
FROM Files_Table
ORDER BY File;
```